# How can I run a multi-line query while using az monitor app-insights query?

Tags: powershell, azure-cli, powershell-core

How can I run a multi-line query while using `az monitor app-insights query`?

This single-line query works as expected:

```
$query = "requests | summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1h)"
az monitor app-insights query --app $appId --analytics-query $query --offset 1h30m
```

This multi-line query results in an error:

```
$query = @"
    requests | 
    summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1h)
"@
az monitor app-insights query --app $appId --analytics-query $query --offset 1h30m
```

Relevant docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/application-insights/monitor/app-insights?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_application_insights_az_monitor_app_insights_query-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but I'd rather use a here-string:

```
$query = 
    "requests | " +
    "summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1h)"

az monitor app-insights query --app $appId --analytics-query $query --offset 1h30m
```